# jquery ajax call messes up the sendt text, when there are at least two questionmarks side by side

Tags: jquery, text

I have a simple message system on my webpage.
Sometimes, vary rarely (so I can not reproduce the error), jquery is messing up the message text.

This is one of the rare text examples, where the error occures:

> *wirklich? sehr cool :) und wie organisiert du das dann immer? schon alles geplant oder wie es dir grad
>   einfälltjQuery172010423805089564042_1347537302675 und wie lange bist
>   du da dann immer unterwegs?*

This string should not be in the text -> jQuery172010423805089564042_1347537302675

The error must occure somewhere between setting the message history -> extracting the text from the textarea -> sending the text via ajax to the server...

Someone has an idea?

```
// The part where I set the text history.
$('#msgwriter_text').val($("<div/>").html('\n' + '\n' + '\n' + old_date + '\n' + old_text).text());

// the part where the new text gets extracted from the textarea.
var text = $('#msgwriter_text').val();

// text will be stored in the database via ajax call
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/ajax_special_functions.php",
    data: data_string,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(recive_obj) {

        // Some more code...
    }
});
```

**finally I discouvered whats causing the error!
This strange string is added, when there are at least 2 questionmarks together in the text -> ??**

now my next question is, how to solve that problem!?
oviously I cant solve the problem by editing the settings of the ajax function - it does not matter, if cache is false or true...

I think the best solution would be, a str.replace with regex, that ensures that there are no ? side by side...

Answer (score 0):

try checking at the values for `old_date` and `old_text`
Also, you need not do it in 2 lines of code, if you just want to get the data, you can get that in 1 line of code.
`var text = '\n' + '\n' + '\n' + old_date + '\n' + old_text;`

Comment: thats not the problem, the ajax call is causing the problem, when there are at least two questionmarks -> ?? side by side in the text

Comment: you can see the ajax function above! By the way, it does not matter, if cache is false or true...

Comment: the above is the ajax call, the ajax function is in ajax_special_functions.php

Comment: the error cant be there, because the text is recived, and almost directly stored to the database... Thats what I think (jquery ajax manual): cache: If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL. It is the query string parameter, which anyhow gets into the text if there are two ?? ...

Comment: whats the value of data_string?